# Swing in moving truck

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, relative-motion

I was just thinking about a situation in which a big truck is moving in high speed say ( $80 \ miles/hr$). There is a swing attached with the ceiling of the truck container which can move freely in the direction of truck motion.

How does the motion of truck affect the swing in which a person wants to play it? What is the path of swing seen from a point outside through the side of truck? Is it a sine wave?

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about acceleration, so it will swing like a normal swing.

Comment: see it https://www.news18.com/news/buzz/watch-man-rides-swing-in-the-back-of-a-moving-truck-in-mumbai-traffic-1903049.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the truck is moving with a constant velocity, a person playing the swing won't notice any difference. The motion as seen from outside will be quite complex, definitely not a sine wave.